# how to fix matplotlip invalid syntax error?

Tags: python, matplotlib, syntax-error, python-3.7, revitpythonshell

i'm trying to run this simple code but keep facing with this error.
i've downloaded everything and searched everywhere but still don't know how to handle this.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()
```

and this is the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TWINS PC\Desktop\test1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\TWINS PC\Desktop\matplotlib.py", line 1
    Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What's `C:\Users\TWINS PC\Desktop\matplotlib.py`? Your code is importing it and it looks to be just invalid Python, that's where your issue lies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works i tested it.
try to import matplotlib in this way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```